# sqlite3 library undefined reference error

Tags: c, string, gcc, sqlite

I am creating a word list searcher in C for my program using sqlite3 but I've got [these errors](http://paste.kde.org/480818/) .
I tried whatever I knew but it didn't fixed. I guess the problem is in my join function but I am not sure.

code :

```
bool *gb_wordlist_add_to_list (gbwordlist *word_list,char *str)
{
int sql_error;
char *error_massage;
if (gb_wordlist_in_list (word_list,str))
    {
    sql_error = sqlite3_execute(word_list->database, gb_wordlist_join(ADD_TO_TABLE_COMMAND"\'",str,"\';"),
                                NULL ,NULL, &error_massage);    
    if( sql_error!=SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", error_massage);
        sqlite3_free(error_massage);
        return 0;
    }

    }
else
    return 0;

}


char *gb_wordlist_join (char *s1,char *s2,char *s3){
char *s;
s = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3) + 1);
if(s)
{
    strcpy(s,s1);
    strcat(s,s2);
    strcat(s,s3);
}
return s;
}
```

error:

```
gb-sql.o: In function `gb_wordlist_remove_from_list':
/home/reza/Project/GB/Search algorithm/Source/gb-search/src/gb-sql.c:104: undefined reference to `sqlite3_execute'
```

Also my full codes are [here](http://paste.kde.org/480824/). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post your `gcc` command?

Comment: I used gnu make. Is configure.ac or makefile.am useful for you?

Comment: Are you #including the right headers, and linking against the right library?

Comment: You need to ensure that the sqlite3 library is being linked and that the `-lsqlite3` (or whatever the library is called) appears at the end of the `gcc` command.

Comment: I used this gcc command: gcc gb-sql.h gb-sql.c main.c -o exec `pkg-config sqlite3  --libs --cflags`
but I've got same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting undefined reference to `sqlite3_execute` is well there is no such function as part of library. You probably meant to use `sqlite3_exec` (which use have used in some parts of the code).
Side Notes:

1. The function `gb_wordlist_callback` is returning `int` but has been declared to return `int*`. You should change the return type to `int` to match the expected parameters to be passed to `sqlite3_exec`(after modifying from `sqlite3_execute`)
2. The 4th parameter passed to `sqlite3_exec` (after modifying from `sqlite3_execute`) is expected to be `void*` so `existance` should be `&existance`
3. You have quite a few functions with mismatch between return type declared and the actual return type returned from the function.
4. Compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra` compiler options & fix all the warnings. It is good practice.

Hope this helps!